# Beamer does not apply alert style when uncovering contents with `<+- | alert@+>` overlay

Tags: beamer

I am trying uncover contents of a slide but I do not get any `alerted text` styling when using `\uncover<+- | alert@+>`. The content are just uncovered.

MWE

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=5cm, sidebar width right=0cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=3mm, text margin right=3mm}
\setbeamersize{description width=0mm}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Uncovering Contents with Alert}

    \begin{block}{Why is induction motor very common}
        %
        \uncover<+->{\phantom{$1$}}\uncover<+->{Induction motors are very practical for the following reasons}

        \begin{description}[<+- | alert@+>]
            \item[Rigid] Rigid
            \item[Cheap] Cheap
            \item[Low Maintenance] Low Maintenance
            \item[Self-Starting] Self-starting
            \item[No Excitation Needed] No Excitation Needed
        \end{description}

        \uncover<+- | alert@+>{Extra content}

    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy workaround:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{rose}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=5cm, sidebar width right=0cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=3mm, text margin right=3mm}
\setbeamersize{description width=0mm}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Uncovering Contents with Alert}

    \begin{block}{Why is induction motor very common}
        %
        \uncover<+->{\phantom{$1$}}\uncover<+->{Induction motors are very practical for the following reasons}

        \begin{description}[<+- | alert@+>]
            \item[Rigid] Rigid
            \item[Cheap] Cheap
            \item[Low Maintenance] Low Maintenance
            \item[Self-Starting] Self-starting
            \item[No Excitation Needed] No Excitation Needed
        \end{description}

        \uncover<+->{\alert<.>{Extra content}}

    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand things correctly, `\uncover<2-|alert@2>{thing}` does not work because `uncover` and `alert` are both what beamer calls "actions". So on overlay 2, we ask it to apply two actions simultaneously, which it seems unable to do, and uncover seems to take precedence.

A solution is to use the generic command `\action`, which takes an overlay specification but does not, in itself, specify a specific action : `\action<uncover@2-|alert@2>{thing}`, or, because uncover is the default action, just `\action<2-|alert@2>{thing}`.

This seems odd, because in a way, we are still telling beamer to apply both actions on overlay 2, but this works.

Comment: The problem aren't simultaneous actions, the problem is using actions in commands like \only, \uncover etc. which do take overlay specifications but don't take actions, they are simply not the correct command for the job.